# Gettin wrong int day from millis

Tags: java, date, time

Im getting timeStamp from Sqlite like this:

```
"timestamp" + " TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP );"
```

This is how i get the date: `2019-06-23 04:25:28`
and i'm transforming to get the days
and im getting this 18070 and not the int day

```
String timestamp = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(VentasContract.TIME_STAMP));
                Log.d("TIEMPO",timestamp);
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                Date date = sdf.parse(timestamp);
                long millis = date.getTime();
                long days = (millis / (60*60*24*1000));
                Log.d("DIA",String.valueOf(days));



  // The value of TIEMPO is 2019-06-23 04:25:28
  // The value of DIA is 18070
```

I expect the current day "23"

Comment: Don't use the old `SimpleDateFormat`, `Date` and `Calendar` classes, but classes from the package `java.time` instead.

Comment: If it’s for (older) Android, consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ).getDayOfMonth()
```

> 23

## Details

Convert your legacy `java.sql.Timestamp` object to a modern `java.time.Instant` object rather than implicitly calling `toString`.

```
Instant instant = myTimestamp.toInstant() ;
```

Adjust to the time zone through which you want to perceive a date and time. Perhaps that is UTC itself.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = instant.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

Extract the day of month.

```
int dom = odt.getDayOfMonth() ;
```

> 23

Tip: The terrible `java.sql.Timestamp` class was supplanted years ago with JDBC 4.2. We can now exchange modern *java.time* objects with the database.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
```

Comment: Thanks this works but just with API > than oreo I think

Comment: @Dskato if you are concerned about Android, you should have mentioned it, and tagged your Question. For Android earlier than 26, see the *ThreeTen-Backport* and *ThreeTenABP* libraires. Both have been addressed many many times already on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

[Date#getTime()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime()) returns the number of milliseconds **since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT** represented by this Date object.

This is quite different from the day of the month.

You should use the `Calendar` class or switch to use the java 8 `LocalDate` class of `java.time` package.